# Java Android client java server code blocks occasionally , how to solve

Tags: java, sockets

[I am asking this because I have checked previous questions and none have answered my questions specific to the code here]

I am relatively new to client server coding. I have Android as client and Java server. The system at the moment works like this:: Android client selects/loads a Jpeg image from sdcard, sends int size, string text and image file to server and server sends back integer and a text file with data back to client

My problem at the moment it works perfectly (randomly) only roughly ~60% of the runs. The remainder of the time it blocks permanently and I have to restart server to continue. [Certainly, a little over half of the time, the client-server system sends and receives without a glitch, but ~40% to 45% (permanent block) failure rate is unacceptable]

When it blocks there is no crash dump, stacktrace or error to read. I have searched previous similar blocking questions and tried to close sockets and inputstream/outputstream and wrappers in different orders varying the permutations, but the success/permanent block rate remained the same

Because there is no stack trace and the randomness, I have no clue what causes the block. Except that using print statements all the server and client code the last prints that hang permanently is in the bytes receiving do-while loop in the server code

I am at a loss on what to do to solve this. I'm hoping experienced minds in this field would help solve this. Full code is below.

Java Server code

```html
public class FileServer {                 

  public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      int bytesRead;     
      int current = 0;   
     //===============================================
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      BufferedInputStream bis = null;
      OutputStream os = null;           
      ServerSocket servsock = null;
      Socket sock = null;                 
      //==============================================
      InetAddress IP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
      servsock = new ServerSocket(57925);      
      System.out.println("IP "+IP.getHostAddress()+"  ***%% :"+servsock.getLocalPort());  

      while (true) {      
        sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

          InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
 //=========================================================
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 //=================== read integer from client ============
          String number = br.readLine();
          System.out.println("integer received from client is "+String.valueOf(number));
           byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [Integer.valueOf(number)];
 //=================== read filename string =====================================  
           String filename = br.readLine();
           System.out.println("integer received from client is "+filename);

//===================== read file data stream bytes ================================
         bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
         current = bytesRead;
         System.out.println("1  bytesRead  "+bytesRead+"  mybytearray.length  "+mybytearray.length);

         do {
             bytesRead =  is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
             if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
             System.out.println("2  current  "+current+"  bytesRead  "+bytesRead);
        } while(current < Integer.valueOf(number));         


        //============================== initialise filename ======================             
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Server root folder\\"+filename+".jpg"); 
          BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
         //========================== write bytes to server HDD =======================       
          bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
          System.out.println("4  current  "+current);

          bos.flush();
          long end = System.currentTimeMillis();   
//          System.out.println("AT SERVER: bytesRead  "+bytesRead+"  current  "+current);
//          bos.close();  
// ======================== write to-be-rendered data to text file ====================== 

          File pathPlusfile = new File("C:/Server root folder/"+filename+".txt");

          appendToFile( pathPlusfile, "file name::  "+filename+"*   *", 20999  );


/**/  //==================   Send Data in text file to Client  ============================================              
          // send file     
          mybytearray  = new byte [(int)pathPlusfile.length()];
          fis = new FileInputStream(pathPlusfile);
          bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
 //===============================================   
          os = sock.getOutputStream();
//=========================== send integer to client ===============                   
          OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
          number = Integer.toString(mybytearray.length);
          String sendMessage = number + "\n";
          bw.write(sendMessage);
          bw.flush();   
//========================== send file to client ===================                
          System.out.println("Sending " + filename + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
          os.flush();
    //========================= close =================================      
          System.out.println("number  "+number);
          System.out.println("Done.");

          bos.close();
          bw.close();
          osw.close();
          os.close();
 //         fos.close();
 //         bis.close();
//          fis.close();
 //         br.close();
          isr.close();
          is.close();

          closeFile(  );               
//           servsock.close();
//           sock.close(); 
     }
  }

  BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
  String stringObjectData = "";
  public int  numFromFile = 0;


     static BufferedWriter  bufferedWriter = null;
    public static  void appendToFile( File myPathPlusFile, String S, int num  ){

       try{
          bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myPathPlusFile, true));
          bufferedWriter.append( S ); 
          bufferedWriter.append( "     " ); 
          bufferedWriter.append( Integer.toString(num) ); 
          bufferedWriter.newLine();
          bufferedWriter.flush();
       }
       catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

     public static  void closeFile(  ){
       try{
          bufferedWriter.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Android Client code

```html
public class FSendfileActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private Socket sock;
    private String serverIP = "192.168.1.4";    
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;
    final static String qcd = "qcd";
    String ImageDir2Client;      
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    Button send;
//====================
    public  static String   FILE_TO_RECEIVED=null;
    String cFilename = null;
    int bytesRead = -1;
    int current = 0;                 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fsendfile);    

        ImageDir2Client = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();                    
        cFilename = "fromServer000019ggg";
        FILE_TO_RECEIVED = ImageDir2Client + "/client root/"+cFilename+".txt";  


        img  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);  

       ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Select Picture" ), SELECT_PICTURE );
            }
       });

       send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);

       send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override                     
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {                  
                   @Override        
                   public void run() {            
                       try {                                     
                        sock = new Socket();     
                        connection(sock,  serverIP, 57925);

            //=================== prepare buffer to read file ====================
                            File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                       //=============== read file from sdcard to buffer ==========     
                            bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            //=================================================================                   
                            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            //============================= send size integer ===================                
                            String number = Integer.toString(mybytearray.length);
                            String sendMessage = number + "\n";
                            bw.write(sendMessage);   // send size integer here
            //============================= send file name =====================
                            String sendMessage2 = cFilename + "\n";
                            bw.write(sendMessage2);   // send size filename here
                            osw.flush();
                            bw.flush();
            //==================================================================                
                            os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length); // send file
                            os.flush();  

    //=================  client receiving data ==============================
                        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        //=================== read integer from client ==========
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        number = br.readLine();
       //========================= set incoming file size=============================
                        mybytearray  = new byte [Integer.valueOf(number)];
        //========================read file bytes in chunks===============================         
                        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                        current = bytesRead;
                        do {
                           bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                           if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                        } while(current < Integer.valueOf(number));

                        fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
                        bos.flush();                                
                        try{        
                            bos.close(); 
                            osw.close();
                            os.close();
              //            fos.close();
              //            bw.close();
              //            br.close();
              //            isr.close();
                            bis.close();
                            sock.close();
              //            fis.close();
                        }        
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }  finally{
                        try{     
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } 
                }
              }).start();
            }
        });

    }       

    public static void connection(Socket s,  String serverIP, int port) {
        try {   
            Log.v(qcd, " before connecting ****...");
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIP, port), 120000);
            Log.v(qcd, " socket connection DONE!! ");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(qcd, " Unknown host..."+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(qcd, " Failed to connect...   "+e);
        }
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                img.setImageURI(null);
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }     
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the code. I've had to test it over again all day long, to make sure it wasn't a false positive, so far its held on.

I hope this answer will help someone.

Originally I was using the same InputStream instance to read integer data, string data and file data at the server and the same outputStream instance to send integer data, string data and file data at the client. And at the client, they were wrapped in bufferOutputstream and bufferWritter and at server they were wrapped in bufferedInputstream and bufferedReader objects.

I think I was losing data at this point and thus the reason for the inconsistency

So to solve I had to create and use separate Outputstream instances for each data sent from the client. (note to send the file byte data - outputstream object wasn't wrapped)

Very subtle but solved it